# How to create row with selected entity in Jpa, RestController Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have 3 Entity A, B, C where C will created though JSON with @OneToOne relation Entity A and @ManyToOne Entity B,
How to send the data using JSON, do I only need to send the ID or complete data of Entity A,B. also I made the relation insertable and updateable falsed, because they dont need to update or create, only need to select among list of value.

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(...)
private Set<B> objB = new HashSet<B>();

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(...)
private A objA;
```

JSON I am posting,

```
{
  "name": "Test Store",
  "description": "Test Description",
  "objB": [
    {
      "id": 19
    }
  ],
  "objA": {
    "id": 1,
  }
}
```

If I send like this, then Object is null for objB and JSON parse error for objA. How I can Handle this. what can be the best approche.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try use like that instead?

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(...)
private List<B> objB;
```

Comment: You mean I should not use set ?